# Google Places API to get Taxi Driver Phone

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am creating an app for users to get details of nearby taxi and I'm trying to use Google Places API.

This is the URL which I'm hitting

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=37.33233141,-122.03121860&radius=20000&types=%7Ctaxi_stand&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCej3iRHphjKOGUxNq0j2bk129bym0sAHY

The problem is it doesn't return any phone number. Is it possible to get Taxi driver's name and phone using this API?

Comment: it is recommended not to post you api key publicily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the phone number, you have to do a followup call per result.
Have a look at https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details

The property you want is 'formatted_phone_number'

Here is an example for one of your results from the URL you provided:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=AIzaSyCej3iRHphjKOGUxNq0j2bk129bym0sAHY&sensor=false&reference=CnRsAAAAyDyREDepw3ELjGswuEyqkYlb-a25URGAvpCnX8VGRm0gj5kh52Tn89Wjk4t9X_XWBcXBmmHeJinih3k33x6qwSl5wkypx7QC2_W_EgRHY_Opwt3IQ_hiF3WmKpZsOZQ7UFEsd0ZzyQsimWk0er-YohIQ1tlr73MpzeOh2glY15m55xoU8JsfK3w-x9rgN55FGa6VhWQLGGY